# Problema al recibir datos del cliente al conectarse al servidor por segunda vez

Tags: c#, socket

Tengo el lado del cliente y el lado del servidor, ambos están en programas diferentes, cuando conecto al cliente por ***segunda vez*** en el lado del servidor, el servidor ya no puede recibir datos "byte[]" del cliente cuando se conecta al servidor.

### Cliente

Aquí es cómo el cliente se conecta al servidor y le envía datos:

```
public class Server
{
    public delegate void ReceiveEvent(Object obj);
    public event ReceiveEvent Receive;
    private byte[] buffer;
    private EndPoint ipServer;
    private string user;
    private Socket socket;

    public Server(string user)
    {
        this.user = user;
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.user = user;
        this.buffer = new byte[8152];
    }

    public void ConnectToServer(IPEndPoint address)
    {
        this.ipServer = address;
        socket.BeginConnect(ipServer, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallBack), null);
    }

    private void ConnectCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(user);
            socket.Send(buffer);
            socket.EndConnect(asyncResult);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        socket.Send(data);
    }
}
```

Modo de uso para conectar al servidor.

```
public class Program
    {
        private Server server;
        private string user;

        public Program()
        {
            this.user = "Admin";
            server = new Server server(user);
            string ip = "127.0.0.1";
            int port = 25565;
            server.ConnectToServer(new System.Net.IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port));
        }
    }
```

### Servidor

El siguiente código recibe el cliente conectado, pero si el cliente se desconecta y vuelve a conectar, en la línea que se comenta a continuación, la variable `usuario` estará vacía.

```
public class Server
    {
        private Socket socket;
        private IPEndPoint ipServer;
        public void Start(IPEndPoint endPoint)
        {
            ipServer = endPoint;
            this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            this.socket.Bind(ipServer);
            this.socket.Listen(0);
            this.socket.BeginAccept(socket.ReceiveBufferSize, OnConnect, null);
            Console.WriteLine($"Server connected in [{ipServer.Address}] : port [{ipServer.Port}]");
        }

        private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[this.socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                Socket socket = this.socket.EndAccept(out buffer, asyncResult);
                string user = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("user '{0}' connected",user); // here
                this.socket.BeginAccept(OnConnect, null);
            }
            catch { throw; }
        }
    }
```

Cómo utilizar para ejecutar el servidor y recibir el cliente:

```
public class Program
    {
        public Program()
        {
            Server server = new Server();
            server.Start(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 25565));
        }
    }
```

Es decir, solo quiero obtener los datos "byte []" iniciales del Cliente cuando se conecta al servidor, cuando se conecta al servidor por primera vez, el servidor puede recibir estos datos, pero si se desconecta y se vuelve a conectar servidor, los datos iniciales "byte []" estarán vacíos.

¿Qué haré para solucionar este problema y cada vez que el cliente se conecte al servidor, el servidor puede obtener los datos iniciales de "byte []"?

Comment: cual es el sentido de definir esto `catch { throw; }` ? para que atrapar un error si lo vas a devolver sin hacer nada

Comment: Es que en este momento estaba depurando los errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la implementacion que buscas es algo mas compleja que la que estas planteando.

Si analizamos estos ejemplos completos de comunicacion asincrona

[Ejemplo de sockets de cliente asincrónicos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example)

[Ejemplo de sockets de servidor asincrónicos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example)

Veras que para iniciar y enviar datos son acciones separadas

- inicia con un `BeginConnect()` y su `ConnectCallback`, pero alli no envia datos
- luego usa el `BeginSend()` y su `SendCallback`, o sea envia datos al servidor y espera la respuesta su fueron recibidos
- para recibir datos del servidor usa `BeginReceive()` y si el servidor envia datos ingresa al `ReceiveCallback`

Como veras usa diferentes acciones para establecer la conexion, enviar o recibir, creo que en tu caso quisiste simplificarlo pero deberias separar un poco estas acciones

El servidor por su parte

- se queda iterando con el uso de `while (true)` la comunicacion con el cliente
- acepta la conexion lo cual lanza el `AcceptCallback`
- es aqui cuando se acepta al cliente que se reciben los datos en el `BeginReceive()` y su `ReadCallback`

Comment: Necesito proporcionarle la información cuando se conecte porque el servidor pegará los datos del cliente y los reproducirá, por ejemplo, no **Dictionary<string, Socket>** y no guardará un cliente que no sea del servidor cuando sea el momento para que el cliente envíe otros datos o el servidor sabrá eso o el cliente está registrado y pegado como información no relacionada con el diccionario.

Comment: no entendi que tiene que ver el Dictionary ? que significa que no guardara un cliente que no sea del servidor? hay algun tipo de validacion si puede conectarse o no?

Comment: Sí, el servidor almacenará y validará los clientes, pero con este problema de no recibir el nombre del cliente al conectarse, no funcionará, ¿entendido?

Comment: compara tu codigo con el del articulo que propuse, algo que notaras es que quieres enviar datos en el la misma accion que usas de callback al establecer la conexion, deberia ver de separar estas acciones